# Scrapy middleware 'NoneType' is not iterable

Tags: python, scrapy

I'm trying to use a middleware with scrapy so in my project named "Tutorial" I have done this:

In the settings file I add:

```
DOWNLOADER_MIDDLEWARES = {
'scrapy.contrib.downloadermiddleware.httpproxy.HttpProxyMiddleware': 110,
'tutorial.middlewares.ProxyMiddleware': 100,
}
```

And also create a file named middlewares.py which contains this:

```
import base64

# Start your middleware class
class ProxyMiddleware(object):
  # overwrite process request
  def process_request(self, request, spider):
    # Set the location of the proxy
    request.meta['proxy'] = "39.179.187.48:8123"
```

When I try to run the project in the shell

```
scrapy shell http://google.com
```

I get the following error:

```
file "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/twisted/internet/threads.py", line 122, in blockingCallFromThread
    result.raiseException()
  File "<string>", line 2, in raiseException
TypeError: argument of type 'NoneType' is not iterable
```

Comment: Are you getting the same error if you would turn of your middleware? (comment it out in settings)

Comment: No, If I commet the section of the middleware I don't get the error

Comment: Wild guess: Your `process_request()` function should be returning something, but it isn't.  Do the scrapy docs tell you to return something there?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the [documentation](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/downloader-middleware.html#scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.DownloaderMiddleware.process_request):

> `process_request()` should either: return None, return a Response
>   object, return a Request object, or raise IgnoreRequest.

You are not returning from your custom middleware's `process_request()` method:

```
class ProxyMiddleware(object):
    def process_request(self, request, spider):
        request.meta['proxy'] = "39.179.187.48:8123"
        return request
```

Returning `request` here assuming you want to reschedule the request with a `proxy` set.